# How is the font being styled here

Tags: html, css, joomla

I came across this template http://demo.joomlaxtc.com/frightnight/# (**WARNING**: Autoplaying, loud sound effects behind link).
I'm not able to identify the font-family being used here in the main menu.
 Digged up the inspect element mode and it shows 'Arial'. However it doesn't look like Arial as the fonts have some shady aspect

[Refer to the screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FDzT.png)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to programming

Comment: Why? It's related to css

Comment: "What font is this?" is related to CSS in much the same way that "Which shade of blue do FedEx use?" — i.e. not much.

Comment: I'm not able to understand how the font are being styled here. I digged up the inspect element mode but it shows 'Arial'. Since the font doesn't look like Arial and styling seems to be different, I've put the question here. Please try to understand and help if you can instead of arguing.

Comment: Perhaps you should rephrase (and retitle) your question to focus on that rather than the identification of the font.

Comment: Thanks for your advise. Done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The font used is called **Downcome**. Here is the link: [Downcome on Dafont](http://www.dafont.com/downcome.font). To find a font used with the Cufon technology you must look at JS files and find the one that end with `.font.js`.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot Pipo. You are awesome :)

Comment: My pleasure! Don't forget to mark the answer as correct ;)

Answer (score 0):

The mainmenu div has the following CSS

```
#mainmenu li a {
text-decoration:none;
font-size:22px;
line-height:32px;
font-family:Arial;
height:32px;
font-weight:700;
padding:0 36px 0 0; 
color:#420807;       
display:block;
```

}

Also [Quentin's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19068/quentin) comment is true. It's not related to programming in any way.

Comment: It doesn't look like arial - See the different styling

Comment: You can refer to the screenshot here - http://prnt.sc/c05rw1
I want to achieve this kind of styling

Comment: It looks like a custom font. While I couldn't figure out what custom font they used. Perhaps a similar "eerie" font style could get your job done?

http://content.altfonts.com:88/img/B/L/BloodyA.png